# Barbarian Advice 5E

Tags: dnd-5e, optimization

I'm currently playing a level 3 Aasimar Barbarian.

I'm not sure whether I want to take the Great Weapon Master feat (-5/+10, when you reduce a creature to 0 HP you can make another attack as a bonus action) or to increase my ability scores. 
I'm a Path of the Lion Barbarian - taken from [here](https://i.redd.it/f47dwtcdc25y.jpg)

My party is actively trying to help me achieve the 5 ft advantage roll(I assume that's important).

The DM had me roll ability scores, and I rolled very averagely. I would usually be content with average rolls, but I have an underwhelming strength (for a barbarian) of 14, and a constitution score of 12.
From my story, I have a magical Greatsword that was a gift from my background, and it does 2d6+2d4 damage right now. It scales with level, so it's 2d6+1d4 at level 1, +2d4 at level 3, +3d4 at level 7, +4d4 at level 15, +5d4 at level 20.

Also from my background, I wear a half-plate, allowing my AC to bump up to 15, which I'm pretty happy with right now.

Current Ability Scores: STR 14; DEX 10; CON 12; INT 9; WIS 9; CHA 11

I'm not sure what else is relevant, but I've been rolling pretty well on my HP level-ups, so I have 34 HP right now.

TL;DR: I'm leveling up to level 4 soon, and I'm not sure how I should "progress" my character with the ASI at 4th level: with a feat or through ability score boosts?

Comment: Hi there, welcome to the site. Questions work best here when there is a clear objective with quantifiable goals, so "Which should I choose" is hard to answer without more information. Are you trying to maximize your damage per round? What is the result you want that you could compare an answer to to see if it is correct?

Comment: Updated your tag; did you add your Assimar racial bonus to the dice rolls to get those ability scores?

Comment: The answer to this is an easy calculation performed several times on this site. Not too broad.